or-tools vrp mutually exclusive disjunction sets?
I am using or-tools vrp framework, and I am trying to create mutually exclusive paths.
Suppose I have 7 different locations [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]. I would like to make my vrp either visit [0,1,2,6] or [3,4,5,6] (in whatever order it deems optimal)
I know that I can use:
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(0), manager.NodeToIndex(1)])

to choose between visiting node 0 or 1.
However, I would like to make a disjunction between 2 sets rather than two nodes. So something like:
routing.AddDisjunction([[manager.NodeToIndex(0), manager.NodeToIndex(1),manager.NodeToIndex(2)],[manager.NodeToIndex(3), manager.NodeToIndex(4),manager.NodeToIndex(5)]])


I found that it is possible to do this by just using multiple disjunctions.
So if you want to force it to go to either {0,1} or {2,3} you can do this as such:
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(0), manager.NodeToIndex(2)])
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(0), manager.NodeToIndex(3)])
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(1), manager.NodeToIndex(2)])
routing.AddDisjunction([manager.NodeToIndex(1), manager.NodeToIndex(3)])

It is a bit cumbersome especially for larger sets, but I haven't found any other method.

Have different vehicles for different sets, and fix the indices in that set to be visited by the mapped vehicle only. So you would have "k" routes with "k" vehicles on "k" mutually exclusive sets.
Then you can choose, which route is the optimal for your use case.
